# Подмена авторизации

Tags: sql-server, active-directory, laravel5

Добрый день!
Разрабатываю сайт на laravel, который в свою очередь соединяется с базой данных mssql. Авторизация в бд происходит через win auth, собственно вопрос в том как обойти эту авторизацию через sql auth.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Создайте для сайта логин входа в БД, реализуйте вход по sql авторизации.

Comment: Так работает, но проблема в том, что входить нужно именно под учетками которые есть у каждого пользователя.

Comment: А в БД все эти виндовые учетки есть?

Comment: Да, учетки есть, но войти с ними не получается, даже если через msms пробовать

Comment: Значит у учеток не хватает разрешений, например в свойствах имени входа не выбрано разрешить подключение

Comment: Сравниваю учетки, ту через которую не дает и ту через которую дает подключится, свойства идентичные.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67325/discussion-between-nick-proskuryakov-and-noanother).